# Rails `remote: true` not making AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

My app uses Rails 5.1 and whenever I click on a `link_to` with `remote: true` I get an `InvalidCrossOriginRequest` error. After turning off forgery protection the app ends up making a full `GET` request to the server and displays the javascript.

*Here is the link:*

```
= link_to 'Example', example_url, remote: true
```

*example.js.erb:*

```
$('.example').html('alert("example message")');
```

*Route:*

```
scope :js, defaults: { format: :js } do
    #### Example
    get 'example', to: 'examples#example'
end
```

*Controller:*

```
def example
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, alert: 'Page not accessible' }
        format.js
    end
end
```

---

I included the javascript in my template:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
```

And I added the necessary js asset paths:

```
//= require_self

// jQuery
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: *The app ends up making a full GET request to the server and displaying the javascript.* What do you expect it to do?

Comment: @Pavan It 'should' make an AJAX request instead. -> `remote: true`

Comment: You mentioned it is *displaying the javascript*. That doesn't mean it is *making AJAX request*?

Comment: In Rails5 you don't need the //=require self part anymore.  So remove that.  Also, your route is specifying ujs format when it should be json right?  Your route should be: scope :ujs, defaults: { format: :json } do

Comment: @Pavan No, it's just wrapping it inside the document body on the screen. That's at least what most browsers do with js.

Comment: @bkunzi01 Seems like that did it. Except, I am now getting a missing template for request format error.

Comment: @bkunzi01 It actually still makes the `GET` request, which then results in the error ...

Comment: You need a js.erb view page or partial to be rendered now.  Checkout "ajax and rails" tutorials and you'll see that now it's looking for an example.js.erb instead of an example.html.erb view file to load the response.

Comment: @bkunzi01 As you can see from my question, I am aware of this... I got that file in the right location

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC BY-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a piece of javascript that I was running:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have specify the format with `respond_to` in your controller :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

Comment: Can you re-try with a normal route ? (Not scoped with `defaults: { format: :js }` )

Comment: I actually tried both. Scoped returns the error named above, unscoped I get a cross origin error - after turning off forget protection it then ends up making a full GET request again. So I am back from where I started.

Comment: (Fuu can't have newline here..)  
Hmm strange, I have just setup a sample project and it worked, here is my config : 

`application.js`  

    //= require rails-ujs
    //= require turbolinks
    //= require_tree .

`home_controller.rb`  

    class HomeController < ApplicationController
      def index
      end
    end

`routes.rb`  

    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      get 'home/index'
    end

`index.html.erb`

    <%= link_to "Here", home_index_path, remote: true %>

`index.js.erb`

    console.log("Hello from ajax");

Comment: The main difference I can see is that I use and load `//= require rails-ujs` before anything else in `application.js`

Comment: This must be a `format` problem. I confirmed, that it recognizes the format as `html`, so it tries to render the corresponding template or do whatever I configured for html formats. Is there a way I can force the format to be `js`?

Comment: You can try to force it like this `= link_to 'Example', example_url(format: :js), remote: true`

Comment: Just weird. It seems like when the format is js, it just appends the js template to the body (it's a full GET request though, the URL changes). Going along with an error caused by forgery protection.